# How to solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{x}\sin\frac{\pi }{t+x}\, \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{x}\sin\frac{\pi }{t+x}\, \mathrm{d}t$$
need some help.

Comment: sub $(t+x)^{-1}=y$ and thinks should become clearer

Comment: Give some context and tell about you thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Using the taylor series of $\sin x$, we have
$$x-\frac{x^{3}}{6}<\sin x<x~,~x>0$$
when $x\to\infty$, $\dfrac{\pi}{x+t}\to0$, so
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\pi }{t+x}\, \mathrm{d}t-\frac{\pi ^{3}}{6}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1 }{\left (t+x  \right )^{3}}\, \mathrm{d}t<\int_{0}^{x}\sin\frac{\pi }{t+x}\, \mathrm{d}t<\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\pi }{t+x}\, \mathrm{d}t$$
Now we only need to calculate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\pi }{t+x}\, \mathrm{d}t$ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1 }{\left (t+x  \right )^{3}}\, \mathrm{d}t$, then use the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and you will get the answer.